# Iterate scrapy crawl over several text files containing URLs

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I've searched for an answer to this question but haven't found it here (but forgive me if I've overlooked it).

I have 20 text files that each contain thousands of URLs (call these text files test1.txt - test20.txt). My goal is to loop my scrapy crawl over the URLs stored in each of these 20 text files and store the data in 20 csv files. Is there a convenient way to do this? I've pasted my spider below, which successfully crawls the URLs from the first file and saves the data.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from proquest.items import ProquestItem
import HTMLParser
import xml.sax.saxutils as saxutils

class ProquestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'proquest'
    f=open("/Users/danny/tutorial/test1.txt")
    start_urls=[url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        items = []
        item = ProquestItem()
        item['date'] = hxs.xpath('./NumericPubDate/text()').extract()
        item['rectype'] = hxs.xpath('./RecordTitle/text()').extract()
        item['pubtitle'] = hxs.xpath('./PubTitle/text()').extract()
        item['fulltext'] = hxs.xpath('./FullText/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        with open('/Users/danny/tutorial/log.txt', 'a') as f:
##            f.write('{0}, {1}, {2}\n'.format(item['date'], item['rectype'], item['pubtitle']))
            f.write('{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}\n'.format(item['date'], item['rectype'], item['pubtitle'], item['fulltext']))
        return items
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__init__` function to initiate the spider with read values from the files.

Something like:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProquestSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    self.start_urls = []
    for i in range(21):  # will go 1 to 20
        with open('file{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as url_file:  #open a file
            self.start_urls.extend([url.strip() for url in url_file.read().splitlines()])
```

this would populate `start_urls` with values from .txt files